# Safe way to use BBCodes?

Tags: php, regex, security, preg-replace, bbcode

I have the following code:

```
function showUser(array $match) {
    global $db;
    $result = $row = $db->select("SELECT Id FROM users WHERE Name=?",
        array($match[1]));
    if ($result!==false) {
        return '<a href="show_profile.php?id=' . $row['Id'] . '"><strong>' . htmlspecialchars($match[1]) . '</strong></a>';
    }

    return $match[0];
}


$text = preg_replace('/\[b\](.*?)\[\/b\]/', '<strong>$1</strong>', $text);
$text = preg_replace('/\[i\](.*?)\[\/i\]/', '<em>$1</em>', $text);
$text = preg_replace('/\[u\](.*?)\[\/u\]/', '<u>$1</u>', $text);
$text = preg_replace_callback('/\[user\](.*?)\[\/user\]/', 'showUser', $text);
```

I would like to know: is this code safe? No injections, and other things? Or should I use things like: `'/\[b\]([a-zA-Z0-9 -\[\]=]+?)\[\/b\]/'`? Thank you!

Comment: I suggest using [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) also for being on safe side to prevent XSS attacks.

Comment: Where are you escaping plain text? ie what stops someone just including `<script>alert('xss');</script>` in the input?

Comment: PHP has a [BBCode class](http://php.net/bbcode).

Comment: Addendum to @JasonOOO : preg_replace_callback() the bbcode tags with a closure that runs the contents through HTML Purifier